# javac allowing file name to be different than Class name in some systems

Tags: java

My Class is

```
public class Foo {}
```

and file name is `Test.java`

But in my system when I compiled its showing the following error

```
test.java:1: class Foo is public, should be declared in a file named Foo.java
public class Foo {
       ^
1 error
```

but in my friends system its getting compiled we both are using oracle JDK

can any one explain why??

Comment: Be more specific about your "friend system". Ohh, and give us the output of `java -version`

Comment: @Ingo. This isn't going to work on any java version.

Comment: Probably on your friend's system the class wasn't public.

Comment: @RohitJain: It could do. It would still be a valid Java compiler if it did. But I suspect it's something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you *certain* it's still public on your friend's system? That would surprise me - if you're both compiling with `javac` from the Oracle JDK, I'd expect both to complain.

That said, it doesn't *have* to be an error. It's optional. From the [JLS section 7.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6):

> If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host system **may choose to enforce the restriction** that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared public (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).

The emphasis is mine, but note that it's an *optional* restriction.

Comment: is there a chance for what I said with openjdk I did not check my friends JDK actually he told me that its Oracle jdk

Comment: @SarathSoman: Maybe, but I think it's more likely that he's just made the class non-public.

Answer (score 1):

For `javac` from the Oracle JDK, what you are witnessing is [not possible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

> Source code file names must have .java suffixes, class file names must have .class suffixes, and both source and class files must have root names that identify the class. For example, a class called MyClass would be written in a source file called MyClass.java and compiled into a bytecode class file called MyClass.class.

Therefore, double check you are both using the exact same source (is `Foo` public in both?) and indeed using Oracle JDK.

This requirement is specific to the Oracle JDK. Other implementations can violate this as it's optional per the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6):

> If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host system **may** choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared public (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).
>
> This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per compilation unit. This restriction makes it easy for a Java compiler to find a named class within a package. In practice, many programmers choose to put each class or interface type in its own compilation unit, whether or not it is public or is referred to by code in other compilation units.